# A better solution to nested ifs

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have wayy too many nested ifs in my code and ive looked up tutorials on how to remove them but they dont seem to work

```
   client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {  
        if (message.channelId === mhc_minor ) {
        if (message.author.bot) {
        if (message.content.startsWith('[') ) { 
        if (message.content.startsWith("[+1 Soul Point]")) { return } ;
        if (message.content.startsWith("[!]")) { return };
        if (message.content.startsWith("[Info]")) { return };
        if (message.content.startsWith("[Event]")) { return };
        if (message.content.startsWith("[Be sure")) { return };
        if (message.content.startsWith("[Sale]")) { return };
        if (message.content.includes("➤")) { 
        if (message.channelId === mhc_minor ) {
          const channel = client.channels.cache.get(mhc_mprivate)
          channel.send(message.content); } return };
          if (message.content.includes('@')) { 
            const contentWithBackticks = message.content.replace(/@(\S+)/g, '`@$1`');
            const channel = client.channels.cache.get(mhc_bfs) 
            channel.send(contentWithBackticks); 
      } else {
          const channel = client.channels.cache.get(mhc_bfs); 
          channel.send(message.content);
  }}}}})
```

works perfectly fine but the nested if look really bad, how do I could them while still getting the same result

Comment: you could move all of the `if` checks at the start into a different function, that would make it slightly more readable

Comment: I would start with properly indenting your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit more readable:

```js
  client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.channelId === mhc_minor && message.author.bot && message.content.startsWith('[')) {
      const prefixes = ['[+1 Soul Point]', '[!]', '[Info]', '[Event]', '[Be sure', '[Sale]'];
      if (prefixes.some(prefix => message.content.startsWith(prefix))) {
        return;
      }
      if (message.content.includes('➤')) {
        if (message.channelId === mhc_minor) {
          const channel = client.channels.cache.get(mhc_mprivate);
          channel.send(message.content);
        }
        return;
      }
      if (message.content.includes('@')) {
        const contentWithBackticks = message.content.replace(/@(\S+)/g, '`@$1`');
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(mhc_bfs);
        channel.send(contentWithBackticks);
      } else {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(mhc_bfs);
        channel.send(message.content);
      }
    }
  });
```

I suspect you might not need the return statements as well (you do not use them is some conditions). If that is true, this would work:

```js
  client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.channelId === mhc_minor && message.author.bot && message.content.startsWith('[')) {
      const prefixes = ['[+1 Soul Point]', '[!]', '[Info]', '[Event]', '[Be sure', '[Sale]'];
      if (!prefixes.some(prefix => message.content.startsWith(prefix))) {
          if (message.content.includes('➤')) {
              if (message.channelId === mhc_minor) {
                  const channel = client.channels.cache.get(mhc_mprivate);
                  channel.send(message.content);
            }
            if (message.content.includes('@')) {
          const contentWithBackticks = message.content.replace(/@(\S+)/g, '`@$1`');
          const channel = client.channels.cache.get(mhc_bfs);
          channel.send(contentWithBackticks);
        } else {
          const channel = client.channels.cache.get(mhc_bfs);
          channel.send(message.content);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Generally indentation should indicate the level of nesting, which is not true in your code - e.g. these two lines should have different nesting:

```
if (message.content.startsWith('[') ) { 
        if (message.content.startsWith("[+1 Soul Point]")) { return }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.channelId === mhc_minor && !message.author.bot) {
    const ignorePrefixes = ["[+1 Soul Point]", "[!]", "[Info]", "[Event]", "[Be sure", "[Sale]"];
    const startsWithIgnorePrefix = ignorePrefixes.some(prefix => message.content.startsWith(prefix));

    if (!startsWithIgnorePrefix) {
      let contentToSend = message.content;
      let channelToSend = mhc_bfs;

      if (message.content.includes("➤")) {
        channelToSend = mhc_mprivate;
      } else if (message.content.includes('@')) {
        contentToSend = message.content.replace(/@(\S+)/g, '`@$1`');
      }

      const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelToSend);
      channel.send(contentToSend);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You can move the code out of the first if clauses if you negate the condition and return instead (early return).